# Setting a position:fixed child to a height/width relative to its parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

How can I set an element with `position:fixed` to a height/width that is relative to its parent?

There's been a question or two about this in the past, but they were only asking how to set the child element to `100%` of the parent width, which is not what I'm asking.

```
#parent {
  height:50%;
  width:50%;
}

#child {
  height:25%;
  position:fixed;
  width:25%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t596t4oc/1/)

As you can see at that link, `#child` is the height and width of `25%` of the document body, not `#parent`, and you can also see `position:relative` is no help.

I understand that in this example I could just set `#child`'s height and width to `12.5%` for the same effect, but that wouldn't be a fix and what if `#parent`'s width is set in `px`?

Answer (score 3):

the simple answer: you can't - "fixed" means it is only dependent on the viewport, not on any other DOM element

BUT: If you use `position: absolute` instead of `fixed`, you should achieve what you are after. Plus: The parent element has to have a `position`setting other than `static`(which is the default). So just use

```
#parent {
  position: relative;
  height:50%;
  width:50%;
}

#child {
  height:12.5%;
  position:absolute;;
  width:12.5%;
}
```

(The height/width settings have to be in relation to the parent element)

Answer (score 1):

If the `#parent` is important to be able to place the `#child`'s position, then make the parent have the `position: fixed;` property this way, the child will still have width relative to its parent when using percentages "%", and in addition it will behave like a `position: fixed;` component because of its parent container.